# binary cross entropy vs multi cross entropy

Tags: logistic, loss-functions, cross-entropy, softmax, log-loss

i am new to neural networks

> **I know that multi class entropy is same as binary class entropy when**
>   **the categories are only (0,1), but can some one explain it**
>   **mathematically with an example that how these two equations give us**
>   **same result.**

I didn't found any mathematical example or where they become the same.

Comment: I changed your tags. While I have no doubt that you're using cross-entropy loss in a neural network, this question deals with the loss functions. How we get the predictions doesn't matter. The predictions could come from a complicated convolutional neural network, or they could come from a logistic regression, and the binary cross-entropy loss function should generalize to categorical cross-entropy.